# Why could not do OneWay binding to ToggleButton IsChecked property?

Tags: wpf, binding, togglebutton

ToggleButton support ICommand, so I create many command such TogglePlayPause, ToggleMute and it work fine but i need to bind IsChecked property too so its checked state always show correct state. but when I create OneWay binding mode for ToggleButton and when I Press ToggleButton, the binding will lost.

The question is why ToggleButton support ICommand but does not support OneWay binding? 
I can set TwoWay binding, but it is bad idea when ToggleButton use Command, because the actual operation handled by Command and it should not be duplicated with TwoWay binding, also some times it is not possible. in my case
Command=TogglePlayPause
IsChecked={Bind to IsMediaPlaying}
IsMediaPlaying should be readonly.

So please tell me how use ToggleButton with Command and bind its IsChecked property?

Answer (score 5):

You can write your own `OneWayToggleButton` by deriving from `ToggleButton` and override what happens when the button is clicked:

```
public class OneWayToggleButton : ToggleButton
{
    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ClickEvent, this));
        if (Command != null && Command.CanExecute(CommandParameter))
            Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
    }
}
```

and then `IsChecked` won't be modified by the button itself and can only be changed via the binding.  But because we are still using the `IsChecked` property of the `ToggleButton`, the control will look and behave normally.

Comment: I can't use this, because interfaces created by other people and I just have its DLL. I do dynamic binding with code so I couldn't use my own override class.

Comment: Then do a two-way binding with your own intermediate property and set it back to its correct value when it is changed by the binding.

Comment: Actually I already apply 2 way binding with not empty set assessor, but it not look good solution, of-course it work but I should change all of my framework readonly properties just for ToggleButton.

I think Silverlight team should solve this issue if there is no other way.

Comment: How do you propose using an intermediate property? I tried letting command set a property and bind IsChecked to that property, but it did not work. User interaction still toggled the button on/off regardless of the binding. The OneWayToggleButton solution worked great though!