# ToggleButton IsChecked Not Adhering to Bound Property

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

So I have a toggle button as follows:

```
  <ToggleButton 
      IsChecked="{Binding IsButtonChecked, Mode=OneWay}"
      Command="{Binding DoNothing}"
      CommandParameter="{Binding ServerViewModel}"
      Content="Click Me!"></ToggleButton>
```

The initial value of **IsButtonChecked = false**

When I click the toggle button the ICommand properly fires (which is bound to a [RelayCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030)) and this command returns false for CanExecute. The state of the WPF ToggleButton is now Checked=true, however the backed model is still **IsButtonChecked = false**.  Why did the UI update to a checked state, even though the bound property hasn't?

### Side Note

The only way I've been able to prevent the UI from updating is creating an inverse property **IsButtonNotChecked**.  I then bind that property to **IsEnabled** in the XAML.  This prevents button clicks from occurring if the state is currently enabled.

Comment: What's the use case of this control? From what you have provided it sounds like you're starting/stopping a server. I have a few more ideas, but I don't want to provide another incorrect one.

Answer (score 0):

You have the binding mode set to `OneWay`, set it to `TwoWay`.

```
<ToggleButton Command="{Binding DoNothing}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding ServerViewModel}"
              Content="Click Me!"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsButtonChecked,
                                  Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Can you post your ViewModel, I just read what you posted again and I get the feeling that something else is going on.

Comment: Updated with my current solution. Every time I set OneWay binding the ToggleButton becomes unchecked when a user clicks it.  The only way I was able to keep it checked was to use TwoWay binding and have the mutator basically do nothing, so that when the user clicked the button, the state was maintained.

Comment: I did see this post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4883037/684869) where someone suggests creating a oneway binding toggle button? Is this even necessary? Seems like this should work out of box.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, here's what I did.. It looks really clunkly.

I set the binding mode to TwoWay. It didn't look like OneWay binding respected the IsChecked property.

```
  <ToggleButton 
      IsChecked="{Binding IsButtonChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
      Command="{Binding DoNothing}"
      CommandParameter="{Binding ServerViewModel}"
      Content="Click Me!"></ToggleButton>
```

Secondly, I no-opp'ed the mutator property of IsButtonChecked.

```
 public bool IsButtonChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return _isButtonChecked;
            }
            set
            {
                // Prevents the IsButtonCheckedfrom incorrectly being set to a
                // enabled state, yet the model is false
                // IsButtonCheckeddoesn't seem to respect OneWay binding.               
            }
        }
```

Then within code behind, I update the _isButtonChecked property and call the INotifyPropertyChanged event.

```
internal void ShouldBeChecked(bool isChecked)
{ 
_isButtonChecked = isChecked;
 OnPropertyChanged("IsButtonChecked"); 
}
```

Really clunky though... Its odd that a ToggleButton doesnt respect the bound property...

Answer (score 0):

As explained in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74686668/2724509) just raise the `PropertyChanged` Event for your `IsButtonChecked`Property as first action in your `DoNothing` Command. With this approach one doesn't need to distort the bound property.

Please check the referenced answer for more details if needed. Added this answer for completeness to lead people finding this question to a possibly less clunky solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set both `Mode=TwoWay` AND `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` before it will work:

```
<ToggleButton 
IsChecked="{Binding IsButtonChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
/>
```